# Applying a filter to an embedded document, filter out distinct values

Tags: c#, mongodb, filter, distinct

So I built out a my filter, on the document and sub document, and then passed that filter into a distinct query.  I want to use that query in my cursor but I'm getting an error, FindAsync cannot be inferred from the usage.  Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

I'm very new to Mongodb...any help would be fantastic.  This works if I just pass the filter, but I need just distinct documents.

```
       var builder = Builders<newMsg>.Filter;
       var filter = builder.Eq("type", "CREATE") & builder.Eq("entities.errorCondition", 14);
    // var result = collection.Find(filter).ToList();
        IList<newMsg> distinct = collection.Distinct<newMsg>("entities.ID", filter).ToList<newMsg>();

        if (distinct.Count > 0)
        {
            using (IAsyncCursor<newMsg> cursor = await collection.FindAsync(distinct))
            {
                while (await cursor.MoveNextAsync())
                {
                    IEnumerable<newMsg> batch = cursor.Current;
                    foreach (newMsg document in batch)
                    {
                        //This gives me the entire list as a string
                        var subDocument = document.Entities;
                        foreach (var sd in subDocument)
                        {
                          //do some stuff

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

my class files look like this

```
    [BsonIgnoreExtraElements]
    internal class newMsg
    {
        [BsonId]
        public ObjectId _id { get; set; }

        [BsonElement("type")]
        public string Type { get; set; }

        [BsonElement("entities")]
        public List<entity> Entities { get; set; }
    }
    [BsonIgnoreExtraElements]
    internal class entity : newMsg
    {
        [BsonElement("errorCondition")]
        public double ErrorCondition { get; set; }

        [BsonElement("ID")]
        public string ID { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I ended up creating 2 loops, 1 for duplicates and another for distinct values, its not beautiful but it worked.

```
        var builder = Builders<newMsg>.Filter;
        var filter = builder.Eq("Type", "CREATE") & builder.Eq("Entities.ErrorCondition", 14) & builder.Eq("MsgRead", false);

        var result = collection.Find(filter).ToList();

        if (result.Count > 0)
        {
            //Create a list of distinct msgs, then set msgRead to True, then pass that list to a new filter  
            var distinctMsg = collection.Distinct(new StringFieldDefinition<newMsg, string>("Entities.ID"), FilterDefinition<newMsg>.Empty).ToList();
            foreach (var dm in distinctMsg)
            {
                var entityID = dm;
                var msgUnread = Builders<newMsg>.Filter.Eq("msgRead", false);
                var msgUpdate = Builders<newMsg>.Update.Set("msgRead", true);
                var msgIsRead = collection.UpdateOne(msgUnread, msgUpdate);

                //Create another filter on the distinct messages
                CreateDistinctFilter(mongoClient, db, collection, entityID, ec);
            }

            using (IAsyncCursor<newMsg> cursor = await collection.FindAsync(filter))
            {
                while (await cursor.MoveNextAsync())
                {
                    IEnumerable<newMsg> batch = cursor.Current;
                    foreach (newMsg document in batch)
                    {
                        //This gives me the entire list as a string
                        var subDocument = document.Entities;
                        foreach (var sd in subDocument)
                        {
                         //log duplicate msg
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

   static async void CreateDistinctFilter(MongoClient mongoClient, IMongoDatabase db, IMongoCollection<newMsg> collection, string entityID, string ec)
    {
        var builder = Builders<newMsg>.Filter;
        var distinctFilter = builder.Eq("Entities.ID", entityID) & builder.Eq("MsgRead", true);
        var result = collection.Find(distinctFilter).ToList();

        using (IAsyncCursor<newMsg> cursor = await collection.FindAsync(distinctFilter))
        {
            while (await cursor.MoveNextAsync())
            {
                IEnumerable<newMsg> batch = cursor.Current;
                foreach (newMsg document in batch)
                {
                    //This gives me the entire list as a string
                    var subDocument = document.Entities;
                    foreach (var sd in subDocument)
                    {
                        string DeviceName = sd.Name;
                        string Title = DeviceName + " Device DOWN";
                        string Msg = sd.Reason + sd.ID;
                        string ErrorCondition = ec;

                        Console.WriteLine("UNIQUE: " + " " + DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss.fff") + Msg );
                        Console.WriteLine();


                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```